# Android Java Textview set text file path

Tags: java, file, textview

how to set the text to a textview from The file directory
After i click the button

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setText("Some text");
    }
 });
```

With this code you can change the text of the button when you click on it